# Flutter: 'package get' has not been run; 'Pub get' has not been run

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I dowloaded a Flutter sample code for [Catalog](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/catalog) from git, which showing me a warning,

> 'package get' has not been run
>   
> 'Pub get' has not been run

What does it mean? How to solve it? Should I ignore this warnings or Update dependencies as suggested with links in warning?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Dart is similar to node.
It has a `pubspec.yaml` which is the equivalent of `package.json` containing your dependencies and stuff.

And you need to download these dependencies, using `pub get`. Or on the case of flutter, using `flutter packages get`.

This warning is just here to reminds you that your dependencies aren't downloaded

=> Click on `Get Dependencies` of the first warning

Comment: Looking for your help here also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056332/flutter-pub-get-failed

Comment: i clicked in get dependencies but problem remains same

Comment: In my case, the warning still show after clicked Get Dependencies and process finished. So I try reload project and warning gone.

Comment: I clicked in get dependencies but problem remains same until I restarted the Android Studio.

Comment: I deactivate the Dart support, so that Flutter can work

Comment: In this case, you have to addenvironment: sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0" to pubspec.yaml and the click on Get Dependencies

Comment: do you need to be in any directory in particular before running flutter packages get? such as cd to the project directory? does this do some kind of virtual environment for that specific project?

Answer (score 11):

The banner `'Pub get' has not been run` did not disappear even after I clicked `Get dependencies` and `Upgrade dependencies`.

Then, after I closed Android Studio and opened the same project again, the banner disappeared.

Comment: Seems like bug..!

Comment: Thank you! This answer saves me a lot of time before I even start to find out why this is happening.

Comment: To me, it shows up whenever I start the Android studio and it never disappears until I click  the Ignore button.

Answer (score 8):

Just restart Android Studio or Your IDE, it worked for me also.
Or
Run *flutter upgrade* in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Reopen the project if the error does not disappear even after downloading dependences.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone's else problem ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click **Get dependencies** and wait for it to finish.
2. Restart Android Studio

Comment: where is 'get dependencies'?

Comment: You can find it in the upper Right of the IDE , Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

This is for anyone who clicks on `Get Dependencies` but doesn't work. All you need to do is:

Step 1: Go to terminal and type `flutter upgrade`

Step 2: Go to `File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart` -> click `Restart`

Step 3: Now just click `Get Dependencies`

That will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the Terminal and run :

`flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Click on the 'Get dependencies' on the banner 'pub get', then the banner will disappear an the dependencies will get downloaded and the errors will disappear.
If still the errors remain then restart Android Studio and try. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]When I face that error, actually I found out that I am in another subfolder. The solution is really easy to delete an extra folder or just cd that subfolder and run "flutter pub get" command.
...
Sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 1):

I tried all solution in this post but nothing help even reopen IDE. Finally I have no choice but click the **Ignore** button:

[image]

This is the last way...  Maybe it's a bug of IDE.

So take it easy and just click Ignore button when you had execute pub get.

**Note: My projects all work well.**

Answer (score 1):

Update your plugins/externals by restarting android studio. It asked for that and then it all worked.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33109239)

Answer (score 0):

if nothing works even after clicking on Get Dependencies and restarting update your android studio IDE that will work

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your Dart entrypoint. Go to File -> Run -> Profile -> Edit Configurations -> New configuration (+ on the top left) -> Flutter and set the Dart entrypoint to your main.dart file. For example:

AndroidStudioProjects/project_foo/lib/main.dart

Then set a device and run the project. The dependencies should resolve automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was happening on the local packages in my project, and clicking on **Get dependencies** was not working.

The reason is that **Get dependencies** on the banner runs the `flutter pub get` on the main root of the project, not that specific package. So the fix would be:

1. Open the Terminal and navigate to each package directory (where you can find the pubspec.yaml for that package) using `cd package_name`
2. Run `flutter pub get`
3. Do it for all your local packages

Answer (score 0):

when clicks on Get Dependencies but doesn't work. All you need to do is:-

1- Go to
[image: pubspec.yaml]

2- click a
[image: Pub get]

in the toolbar

3- congratulations! done does work now :D

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct way i am try it , It works normally

To solve this error in the EASIEST WAY follow below steps :

1. Go to terminal
2. Then find local tabs
3. Then click on a '+' sign and type your command.This should solve your error