# Flutter: pub get failed

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-pub

Flutter project showing me a warning `'Packages get' has not been run` with suggested solutions,

- Get Dependencies
- Upgrade Dependencies
- Ignore

As suggested by [Darky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8394265/darky), in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49056175/5638630) to go ahead with 'Get Dependencies'

I tried it but it shows me an error:

> **pub get failed**

```
/SoftSources/Flutter/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in catalog...
Incompatible version constraints on test:
- flutter_test 0.0.0 depends on version 0.12.30+3
- sample_catalog depends on version 0.12.30+4
pub get failed (1)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

An error indicates an issue with the version of the project (or something else), where should change it in my flutter project?

**Edit:** *pubspec.yaml*

```
name: sample_catalog
description: A collection of Flutter sample apps
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path: 1.5.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter

  args: 1.3.0 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  async: 2.0.4 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  barback: 0.15.2+14 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  boolean_selector: 1.0.2 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  charcode: 1.1.1 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  cli_util: 0.1.2+1 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  collection: 1.14.5 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  convert: 2.0.1 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  crypto: 2.0.2+1 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  csslib: 0.14.1 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  file: 2.3.6 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  glob: 1.1.5 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  html: 0.13.2+2 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  http: 0.11.3+16 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  http_multi_server: 2.0.4 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  http_parser: 3.1.1 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  intl: 0.15.2 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  io: 0.3.2+1 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  isolate: 1.1.0 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  js: 0.6.1 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  json_rpc_2: 2.0.7 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  logging: 0.11.3+1 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  matcher: 0.12.1+4 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  meta: 1.1.2 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  mime: 0.9.6 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  mockito: 2.2.3 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  multi_server_socket: 1.0.1 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  node_preamble: 1.4.0 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  package_config: 1.0.3 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  package_resolver: 1.0.2 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  plugin: 0.2.0+2 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  pool: 1.3.4 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  pub_semver: 1.3.2 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  quiver: 0.28.0 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  shelf: 0.7.2 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  shelf_packages_handler: 1.0.3 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  shelf_static: 0.2.7 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  shelf_web_socket: 0.2.2 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  source_map_stack_trace: 1.1.4 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  source_maps: 0.10.4 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  source_span: 1.4.0 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  stack_trace: 1.9.1 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  stream_channel: 1.6.3 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  string_scanner: 1.0.2 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  term_glyph: 1.0.0 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  test: 0.12.30+4 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  typed_data: 1.1.5 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  utf: 0.9.0+4 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  vector_math: 2.0.5 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  vm_service_client: 0.2.4+1 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  watcher: 0.9.7+7 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  web_socket_channel: 1.0.7 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY
  yaml: 2.1.13 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: `sample_catalog` seems to have dependency constraint that conflict with constraints in your `pubspec.yaml` or other dependencies of your project.

Comment: can you show us your `pubspec.yaml` ? It seems like there's a version conflict on some of your packages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace inside your devDependencies

`test: 0.12.30+4 # TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCY`
with
`test: 0.12.30+3`

Or you can potentially switch to master branch on flutter. Because you most likely clone an example of a project based on flutter's master

Answer (score 8):

For [Flutter](http://flutter.io) projects run

```
flutter packages get
```

Instead of

```
pub get packages
```

Answer (score 2):

People who you are from **Windows OS** and still cannot solve `pub get failed (1; no message) exit code 1` problem, you can try the below steps:

1. Open `Start -> Run -> regedit`
2. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun` (If it doesn't exist, create a String value)
3. Change the value to `@chcp 65001>nul`
4. Run `flutter upgrade --force`
5. Run `flutter pub get` in your **flutter project folder**

If it's not showing `pub get failed` anymore, then you can run your app in your app emulator or physical device.

**Note:** This may take some time to run your app.

Last but not least, `pub get failed` was a horrible error for me!

Solution collected from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63112#issuecomment-691620053)

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Link get packages in the given environment like VS code
or 
save your code while **pubspec.yaml** file is opened will get flutter packages for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Check syntax in pubspec.yaml, it should look like this

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    
  provider: ^6.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

What I had was like this which was incorrect.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter    
    provider: ^6.0.0
    cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

The other thing is check for syntax errors in other files such as missing ] or ). I had both the issues, once that were fixed, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case with a similar error, I specified `intl: 0.18.0`  in the dependencies. After removing it, everything worked fine.

Comment: There is no wrong with intl package if any case complier will notify it

Comment: @KasunHasanga You may be right, but in my case, it helped solve a similar problem. Other than removing the intl package I didn't do anything.

Comment: Same here. I had a similar problem and removing intl: 0.18.0 solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

1.Updating Flutter will not work

2.Restarting PC will not work

3.Creating new project and running pub get will not work.

Then only solution is to use VPN for the time being. There are some network issue which is causing the issue.