# Can't resolve flutter pub get exit code 0

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I'm new to Flutter and when making a new application I keep getting `'Pub get' has not been run`
Whenever I click get dependencies I get this error:

[image]

Been looking around for solutions for 3 hours but nothing worked so far.

This is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: testproject
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.2 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

These are my environmant variables:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What error? Exit code 0 is good. A successful command exits with code 0.

Comment: Then why is the 'pub get' message not going away. It's been there the whole time and was bothering me sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: Have you tried restarting your IDE?

Comment: Yes it's the first thing that pops up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66700668/13263384

Comment: Either way. Exit code 0 is not an error.

Comment: I've already been on that post, but it didn't solve anything